# Image transition automatically starts after clicking next or prev buttons in manual mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/KmXEg/

I have three buttons visible:

- stop (visible in first place but becomes invisible after clicking
  start button) - stop automatic transition and make it manual
- start (becomes visible after clicking stop button) - start automatic 
  transition
- previous and next buttons

When clicking stop, transition stops which is fine however after clicking previous or next button to navigate through images, transition starts again itself which is wrong. Also it starts itself, start button appears instead of stop.

How it should work is, when I stop it, I should be able to navigate myself with prev and next buttons.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

**JS**

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var timeoutId;                                                              //To store timeout id

                var slideImage = function(step)
                {
                    if (step == undefined) step = 1;                                        //If undefined then set default value

                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout if any

                    var indx = $('.slide:visible').index('.slide');                         //Get current image's index

                    if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
                    {
                        $('.slide:visible').fadeOut();                                      //Fadeout this slide
                    }

                    indx = indx + step;                                                     //Increment for next slide

                    if (indx >= $('.slide').length)                                         //Check bounds for next slide
                    {
                        indx = 0;
                    }
                    else if (indx < 0)
                    {
                        indx = $('.slide').length - 1;
                    }

                    if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
                    {
                        $('.slide:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();                              //Fadein next slide
                    }

                    timeoutId = setTimeout(slideImage, 5000);                               //Set Itmeout
                };

                slideImage(0);                                                              //Start sliding

                $('#prev').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on prev
                {
                    slideImage(-1);                                                         //SlideImage with step = -1
                });

                $('#next').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on next
                {
                    slideImage(1);                                                          //SlideImage with step = 1
                });

                $('#stop').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Pause
                {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout

                    $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Pause and show Play
                    $('#play').show();
                });

                $('#play').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Play
                {
                    slideImage(0);                                                          //Start slide image

                    $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Play and show Pause
                    $('#stop').show();    
                });
            });
```

**CSS**

```
* {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                font-family:arial;
                font-size:12px;
            }
            #cover {
                margin-top:50px;
                width:100%;
                height:300px;
                background:#EEEEEE;
            }
            #slides {
                width:100%;
                height:300px;
                position:absolute;
            }
            .slide {
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:300px;
                display:none;
            }
            .slide img {
                width:100%;
                height:300px;
            }
            .first {
                display:block;
            }
            #controls {
                position:relative;
                top:240px;
                text-align:right;
            }
            #controls img {
                width:48px;
                height:48px;
                cursor:hand;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            #play {
                display:none;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="cover">
            <div id="slides">
                <div class="slide first"><img src="images/1.gif" /></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="images/2.gif" /></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="images/3.gif" /></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="images/4.gif" /></div>
            </div>
            <div id="controls">
                <img id="prev" src="images/prev.png" />
                <img id="play" src="images/play.png" />
                <img id="stop" src="images/stop.png" />
                <img id="next" src="images/next.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
                var timeoutId;                                                              //To store timeout id

                var slideImage = function(step, request)
                {
                    if (step == undefined) step = 1;                                        //If undefined then set default value

                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout if any

                    var indx = $('.image:visible').index('.image');                         //Get current image's index

                    if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
                    {
                        $('.image:visible').fadeOut();                                      //Fadeout this slide
                    }

                    indx = indx + step;                                                     //Increment for next slide

                    if (indx >= $('.image').length)                                         //Check bounds for next slide
                    {
                        indx = 0;
                    }
                    else if (indx < 0)
                    {
                        indx = $('.image').length - 1;
                    }

                    if (step != 0)                                                          //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
                    {
                        $('.image:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();                              //Fadein next slide
                    }

                    if (request != 'manual')
                    {
                        timeoutId = setTimeout(slideImage, 1000);                               //Set Itmeout
                    }
                };

                slideImage(0, 'auto');                                                              //Start sliding

                $('#prev').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on prev
                {
                    slideImage(-1, 'manual');                                                           //SlideImage with step = -1

                    $('#stop').hide();
                    $('#play').show();
                });

                $('#next').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on next
                {
                    slideImage(1, 'manual');                                                            //SlideImage with step = 1

                    $('#stop').hide();
                    $('#play').show();
                });

                $('#stop').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Pause
                {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);                                                //Clear timeout

                    $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Pause and show Play
                    $('#play').show();
                });

                $('#play').click(function()                                                 //When clicked on Play
                {
                    slideImage(0, 'auto');                                                          //Start slide image

                    $(this).hide();                                                         //Hide Play and show Pause
                    $('#stop').show();    
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a new timeout in the slideImage function, even if the slider is stopped. At the moment when you call `slideImage` a timeout is set at the end of the function to call `slideImage` again (thus resuming automatic playback).

Remove the code there, put it into the play function the code to the play function and use setInterval.

Something like this:

```
$('#stop').click(function () {
    clearInterval(timeoutId);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});
$('#play').click(function () {
    slideImage(0);
    timeoutId = setInterval(slideImage, 1000);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#stop').show();
});
```

Comment: I removed `timeoutId = setTimeout(slideImage, 1000);` and added your code but it doesnt start when the page loads.

Comment: You would need to trigger `$('#play').click()` on page load.

Comment: Even if I do that navigation permanently becomes manual. I should be able stop it and navigate manually or it should slide images automatically after clicking play.